# Excel =IF(ISBLANK ... ) not working

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have (letters up top are column names):

```
|  J |  M    |   N   |  O  |
|    |kennedy|  2    |   4 |
|    |nixon  |   3   |   2 |
|    |       |   8   |     |
|    |  bush |       |     |
|    |       |       |     |
|    |       |       |     |
```

If Column M is blank, J should be zero (same row)
If Column M is filled, N should be added up with O.

This is what I have tried (placed in `J2`):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(M2),0,N2+O2))
```

Could someone please explain why this does not work/what does?

Answer (score 0):

For vanilla Excel, the following code does exactly what you want:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(M2),0,N2+O2)
```

Using semi-colons is not standard. Does the following work for you?

```
=CONCATENATE("Suc","cess")
```

Your versions of Excel and Windows may be important to discovering idiosyncrasies like this in the future.